# Gravar áudio igual ao whatsapp

Tags: java, android

Alguém sabe como fazer para gravar um áudio enquanto o botão esta pressionado e parar quando soltar o botão igual o Whatsapp?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode usar o método [`setOnTouchListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) no botão para para resgatar o toque. O `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` é o evento que captura o momento em que você clicou no botão. Já o `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` é quando remover o dedo do botão. Veja um exemplo abaixo:

```
class MyActivity extends Activity {

     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

         Button myBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
         myBtn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
             @Override
             public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                 switch (event.getAction()) {
                     case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                         // aqui código de iniciar a gravação que é o momento
                         // em que pressionou o botão para baixo
                         return true; 

                     case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                         // aqui código de pausar a gravação que é o momento
                         // em que soltou o botão
                         return true; 
                 }
                 return false;
             }
         });
     }

 }
```

Comment: Muito bom, obrigado novamente Ack..

Comment: @WallaceRoberto por nada bro! Precisar, só recorrer aqui! =D